# meaning of the following php code?

Tags: php

Guys I have been using the following code quite often but haven't properly understood the exact semantics of the functions. 
Especially for the last two str_replace functions. Can anybody explain me whats exactly happening here(in a little detail)?

```
$this_file = str_replace('\\', '/', __FILE__);
$doc_root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
$web_root = str_replace(array($doc_root, 'application/config.php'), '', $doc_root);
$srv_root = str_replace('application/config.php', '', $doc_root);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Replace the backslashes `\` with forward slashes `/` (the variable is not used after that).
2. Get the document root from the server super-global (typically will be the Apache config DocumentRoot directive).
3. Replace any occurence of the document root or `application/config.php` from the document root string  and store it in `$web_root` (seems like useless code to me).
4. Replace any occurence of `application/config.php` from the document root string and store it in `$srv_root` (again, seems like useless code, because a document root should be a directory, not a file).

Conclusion: It seems like this code could be translated into the following, and that none of these "calculations" are actually necessary:

```
$doc_root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
$web_root = '';
$srv_root = $doc_root;
```

Or even shorter:

```
$doc_root = $srv_root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
$web_root = '';
```

Comment: well..i cant challenge u coz i am relatively new to php but i am pretty sure its not useless code coz when i was searching for a solution i came across a no. of sites that used that kind of definition. here is one example - http://www.phpwebcommerce.com/source/library/config.php

Comment: user597272: Well that's different. In that example you just posted, it's manipulating `$thisFile`, not `$doc_root`. That would change everything.

Comment: hmmm...i understood now what ur saying but can u explain me why in ur modified code  does the last line evaluate to $srv_root = $doc_root ?

Comment: The last line replaces an occurence of `application/config.php` from the document root. However, the document root will most likely never contain that string because it has to be a path, not a file. So, replacing a non-occuring string will return the input string as is. Hence `$srv_root = $doc_root`.